# Surface Pro 4 Task bar mouseover glitchy in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-surface-pro-4

Hovering over an item on the task bar with the mouse cursor should normally give a preview of the target application.

1. When I mouseover an icon on the taskbar, the thumbnail of available window or windows does appear, but on moving the cursor even a pixel, the preview quickly disappears. This can take anywhere between an instant and a couple of seconds
2. If the thumbnail does not disappear, it is possible to move the cursor over the thumbnail, something which should normally give a lightbox preview of the application window. This does not happen at all.

The instancy of the disappearance of the thumbnail makes window selection cumbersome and annoying. Far too often, the attempt to click a thumbnail to open the window fails by its sudden vanishing, and I end up clicking something unwanted in the already open window in the background.

Does anyone have any experience, or even better, solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem. Here's a test you can do: unplug the surface from power supply, so it runs only on battery. Does the problem disappear for you? I have found other users with the same issue here:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfbook-surfperf/surface-book-taskbar-previews-close-too-quickly/9ed9987b-fc69-4933-acf1-73d087ffe905

I have yet to find a resolution, it seems that the root cause is buggy battery drivers, so it might be a case of waiting and hoping that MS will fix....

Comment: Thanks Anthony! Unplugging the charger made the annoying disappearance of the thumbnail stop, but like you said - it's not a solution. If nothing else, it's a clue.. If I find anything, I'll post it here.
-B